# Access method of object in an array A in an array B

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
public Object[][] method1() {
 int accountNumber = 123, pin = 123;
 double balance = 123;

 CurrentAccount currentAccounts = new CurrentAccount(accountNumber, pin, balance);
 SavingsAccpunt savingsAccounts = new SavingsAccount(accountNumber, pin, balance);

 Object[][] bankDB = { currentAccount, savingsAccounts }

 return bankDB;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
 Object[][] bankDB;

 bankDB = method1();
}

class CurrentAccount {
 private int accountNumber;
 private int pin;
 private double balance;

 CurrentAccount(int accountNumber, int pin, double balance) {
  this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
  this.pin = pin;
  this.balance = balance;
 }

 public int accountNumber() {
  return this.accountNumber;
 }
}
```

I am very new to coding, I need to return both current account and savings account object back to the main class and access the methods. How do I `System.out.println()` out the account number of current account class?

Edit: I found the solution.

```
CurrentAccount currentAccount = (CurrentAccount) bankDB[0][0];
System.out.println(currentAccount.accountNumber());
```

The first `[0]` in `bankDB[0][0]` is currentAccount in bankDB object `( bankDB = {`**currentAccount**`, savingsAccounts }`, the second `[0]` is the first index in the array of object `CurrentAccount currentAccounts`.

Comment: `class Object[][] method1() {` ?

Comment: What does **class Object[][] method1()** mean, does it even compiles ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to make this work, but one way would be with a _cast_ - something like `System.out.println(((CurrentAccount) bankDB).accountNumber());`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you -

```
public static Object[] method1() {
    int accountNumber = 123, pin = 123;
    double balance = 123;

    CurrentAccount currentAccounts = new CurrentAccount(accountNumber, pin, balance);
    SavingsAccount savingsAccounts = new SavingsAccount(accountNumber, pin, balance);

    Object[] bankDB = { currentAccounts, savingsAccounts };

    return bankDB;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Object[] bankDB;

    bankDB = method1();
    CurrentAccount currentAccount = (CurrentAccount) bankDB[0];
    SavingsAccount savingsAccounts = (SavingsAccount) bankDB[1];
    System.out.println("Current AccountNumber => "+ currentAccount.accountNumber);
    System.out.println("Saving Account Number => "+ savingsAccounts.accountNumber);
}
```

Comment: i got this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: I changed all my Object[][] to Object[] and added last 4 lines in main method

Comment: I got the error at this line: CurrentAccount currentAccount = (CurrentAccount) bankDB[0];

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [LBANK.CurrentAccount; cannot be cast to BANK.CurrentAccount

Comment: did you change your method to not use class ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code.Write separate class and try .

```
public class CurrentSavingAccount {
 static Object[] method1() {
    int currentAccountNumber = 123, savingAccountNumber = 456,pin = 123;
    double balance = 123;

    CurrentAccount currentAccounts = new CurrentAccount(currentAccountNumber , pin, balance);
    SavingAccount savingsAccounts = new SavingAccount(savingAccountNumber , pin, balance);

    Object[]bankDB = { currentAccounts, savingsAccounts };

    return bankDB;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Object[] bankDB;
    bankDB = method1();
    CurrentAccount currentAccount = (CurrentAccount) bankDB[0];
    SavingAccount savingsAccount = (SavingAccount) bankDB[1];
    System.out.println("Current Account Number: "+ currentAccount.getAccountNumber());
    System.out.println("Saving Account Number: "+ savingsAccount.getAccountNumber());
     }} 


class CurrentAccount {
private int accountNumber;
private int pin;
private double balance;

CurrentAccount(int accountNumber, int pin, double balance) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}}

  public class SavingAccount{
    private int accountNumber;
    private int pin;
    private double balance;

    SavingAccount(int accountNumber, int pin, double balance) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}}
```

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [LBANK.CurrentAccount; cannot be cast to BANK.CurrentAccount